# Character is frozen on Pygame game

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, pygame

I drafted up some code that test out animation on a pygame program I made.  The interpreter goes through it cleanly, yet when I try to run it, it stays frozen.  The X button doesn't work, and the player character stays frozen in the corner, and will not move at all.

The terminal window is outputting no errors at all, and I'm stuck to as how it is not moving or not. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

faceWhatDirection = 4
keyDown = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #constructor function
    def __init__(self): #what this is doing is declaring a self variable and an x and y varible

        #call up the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #List of images for different types of movement
        self.imagesLeft = []

        self.imagesRight = []

        self.imagesUp = []

        self.imagesDown = []

        #load the up images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_bk1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesUp.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_bk2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesUp.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the down images

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_fr1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesDown.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_fr2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesDown.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the left images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_lf1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesLeft.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_lf2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesLeft.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the right images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_rt1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesRight.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_rt2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesRight.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #the best image to use by default is the one that has the player facing the screen.
        self.image=self.imagesDown[0]

        #This line of code, as the Programming website showed me, gets the dimensions of the image
        #Rect.x and rect.y are the coordinates of the rectangle object, measured at the upper right
        #hand corner

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def changeImage(self):

        ##
        ##  FUNCTION THAT UPDATES THE IMAGES AND CYCLES THROUGH THEM
        ##

        #if player is going left
        while faceWhatDirection == 1 and keyDown == True:
            self.image =self.imagesLeft[0]
            self.image =self.imagesLeft[1]

        #if player is going right
        while faceWhatDirection == 2 and keyDown == True:
            self.image =self.imagesRight[0]
            self.image =self.imagesRight[1]

        #if player is going up
        while faceWhatDirection == 3 and keyDown == True:
            self.image =self.imagesUp[0]
            self.image =self.imagesUp[1]

        #if player is going down
        while faceWhatDirection == 4 and keyDown == True:
            self.image =self.imagesDown[0]
            self.image =self.imagesDown[1]






#initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#set the height and width of the screen
width = 800
height = 480

mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])

#A list off all of the sprites in the game
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#creates a player object
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#a conditional for the loop that keeps the game running until the user Xes out
done = False

#clock for the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #user did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the user hit the close button
                done=True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # if the user pushes down a key
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.x -=1
                faceWhatDirection = 1
                keyDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.x +=1
                faceWhatDirection = 2
                keyDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.y -=1
                faceWhatDirection = 3
                keyDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.y +=1
                faceWhatDirection = 4
                keyDown = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: # if the user pushes down a key
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                keyDown = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                keyDown = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                keyDown = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                keyDown = False


    mainScreen.fill(white)#makes the background white, and thus, the white part of the images will be invisible
    player.changeImage()

    #draw the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(mainScreen)

    #limit the game to 20 fps
    clock.tick(20)

    #update the screen on the regular
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your `changeImage()` function looks strange. I think when you hit an arrow key your global `keydown` changes to `True`and the program gets stuck inside `changeImage()` in one of the while loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this bit:

```
def changeImage(self):

    ##
    ##  FUNCTION THAT UPDATES THE IMAGES AND CYCLES THROUGH THEM
    ##

    #if player is going left
    while faceWhatDirection == 1 and keyDown == True:
        self.image =self.imagesLeft[0]
        self.image =self.imagesLeft[1]

    #if player is going right
    while faceWhatDirection == 2 and keyDown == True:
        self.image =self.imagesRight[0]
        self.image =self.imagesRight[1]

    #if player is going up
    while faceWhatDirection == 3 and keyDown == True:
        self.image =self.imagesUp[0]
        self.image =self.imagesUp[1]

    #if player is going down
    while faceWhatDirection == 4 and keyDown == True:
        self.image =self.imagesDown[0]
        self.image =self.imagesDown[1]
```

In order for any of the `while` loops to end, the face direction needs to change, and the key needs to be lifted. However, there's no possible way for that to happen, since to code to change either of those is inside the mainloop.

In addition, changing the image twice is redundant. If you're trying to do animation, you need to remember to call `pygame.display.flip()` between each image change.

---

Instead, I would write your code to look something like the below. (Warning! I haven't tested this code, since I don't have the image files, so there may be a few bugs here and there. I'm assuming that the gifs are not animated)

```
import pygame
import sys

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self): 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.images = {
            'left': self.load_animation('man1_lf1.gif', 'man1_lf2.gif'),
            'right': self.load_animation('man1_rt1.gif', 'man1_rt2.gif')
            'up': self.load_animation('man1_bk1.gif', 'man1_bk2.gif')
            'down': self.load_animation('man1_fr1.gif', 'man1_fr2.gif')
        }

        self.direction = 'down'
        self.moving = False

        # Arbitrary starting coordinates
        self.x = 5
        self.y = 5

    def load_animation(self, *names):
        output = []
        for name in names:
            img = pygame.image.load(name).convert()
            img.set_colorkey(white)
        return output

    @property
    def image(self):
        seconds = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000  
        # Returns the time in milliseconds since the game started
        image_index = seconds % 2:

        # Returns a new image every second
        if self.moving:
            return self.images[self.direction][image_index]
        else:
            return self.images[self.direction][0]

    @property
    def rect(self):
        image_rect = self.get_image().get_rect()
        return pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), image_rect.size)


def main():
    pygame.init()

    width = 800
    height = 480
    mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])

    player = Player()

    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                    player.moving = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                player.moving = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.x -= 1
                    player.direction = 'left'
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.x += 1
                    player.direction = 'right'
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
                    player.y -=1
                    player.direction = 'up'
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.y +=1
                    player.direction = 'down'


        clock.tick(20)

        mainScreen.fill(white)
        all_sprites_list.draw(mainScreen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice how inside the `Player` class, I've used properties. This lets me do something like `my_player.image` (notice that this is not a function!) and get an image from calling the `image` function. Basically, properties allow functions to look like attributes.

Using properties, I can make the player automatically animate itself so it changes its image every second if it's moving.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help Michael0x2a.

I'm still a newbie at this, so I took a longer and less efficient route to handle the program.

Here is my code for anyone who is looking at this question:

```
#help from ProgramArcadeGames.com
import pygame

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

faceWhatDirection = 4
keyDown = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #constructor function
    def __init__(self): #what this is doing is declaring a self variable and an x and y varible

        #call up the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #List of images for different types of movement
        self.imagesLeft = []

        self.imagesRight = []

        self.imagesUp = []

        self.imagesDown = []

        #load the up images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_bk1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesUp.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_bk2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesUp.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the down images

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_fr1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesDown.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_fr2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesDown.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the left images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_lf1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesLeft.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_lf2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesLeft.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #load the right images
        img = pygame.image.load("man1_rt1.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesRight.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        img = pygame.image.load("man1_rt2.gif").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white) #sets the color key. any pixel with the same color as the colorkey will be transparent
        self.imagesRight.append(img) #adds the image to the list

        #the best image to use by default is the one that has the player facing the screen.
        self.image=self.imagesDown[0]

        #This line of code, as the Programming website showed me, gets the dimensions of the image
        #Rect.x and rect.y are the coordinates of the rectangle object, measured at the upper right
        #hand corner

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #getter for the image

    def updateLeft(self):

            #code block for handling the left movement animations
            if self.image == self.imagesLeft[0]:
                self.image = self.imagesLeft[1]
            else:
                self.image = self.imagesLeft[0]

    def updateRight(self):

            #code block for handling the right movement animations
            if self.image == self.imagesRight[0]:
                self.image = self.imagesRight[1]
            else:
                self.image = self.imagesRight[0]


    def updateUp(self):

            #code block for handling the right movement animations
            if self.image == self.imagesUp[0]:
                self.image = self.imagesUp[1]
            else:
                self.image = self.imagesUp[0]

    def updateDown(self):

            #code block for handling the right movement animations
            if self.image == self.imagesDown[0]:
                self.image = self.imagesDown[1]
            else:
                self.image = self.imagesDown[0]








#initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#set the height and width of the screen
width = 800
height = 480

mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])

#A list off all of the sprites in the game
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#creates a player object
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

#a conditional for the loop that keeps the game running until the user Xes out
done = False

#clock for the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #user did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the user hit the close button
                done=True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # if the user pushes down a key
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.x -=15
                faceWhatDirection = 1
                player.updateLeft()     

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.x +=15
                faceWhatDirection = 2
                player.updateRight()

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.y -=15
                faceWhatDirection = 3
                player.updateUp()

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #if the left arrow key is pressed
                player.rect.y +=15
                faceWhatDirection = 4
                player.updateDown()


    mainScreen.fill(white)#makes the background white, and thus, the white part of the images will be invisible
    #player.changeImage()

    #draw the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(mainScreen)

    #limit the game to 20 fps
    clock.tick(20)

    #update the screen on the regular
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```